# JQuery disable inputs during ajax submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I'm creating a form using Django, JQuery and JQuery Form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and I want to disable my form's fields while waiting for server response. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#load').hide();
        $('#error').hide();
        $('#success').hide();
        var myForm = $(this).find('input'); //finding all inputs
        $('#save').live('click', function () {
            $('#save_form').ajaxSubmit({
                success:function (data, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    alert('success');
                    $form.find('.error').remove();
                    if (data['result'] == 'success') {
                        $('#success').show("slow");
                    }
                    else if (data['result'] == 'error') {
                        $('#error').show("fast");
                        //calling procedure to show errors
                    }
                    $('#load').hide("fast");
                },
                beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
                    $('#error').hide();
                    $('#success').hide();
                    $('#load').show("fast");
                    $(myForm).attr('disabled', true);
                    alert('before submit');
                    return true;
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Failed to submit!");
                    $('#load').hide("fast");
                },
                timeout: 3000,
                dataType:'json'
            });
        });
    })
```

So when I press Save I see that inputs are disabled and I'm getting 'before submit' alertbox, but when I press OK all inputs become enabled even If i switch off responding server.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe u can disable your form in click func, and then enable in success

```
$('#save').live('click', function () {

            $(myForm).attr('disabled', true);
            alert('before submit');

            $('#save_form').ajaxSubmit({
                success:function (data, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    $(myForm).attr('disabled', false);
                    alert('success');
                    $form.find('.error').remove();
                    if (data['result'] == 'success') {
                        $('#success').show("slow");
                    }
                    else if (data['result'] == 'error') {
                        $('#error').show("fast");
                        //calling procedure to show errors
                    }
                    $('#load').hide("fast");
                },
.
.
.
```

Comment: if I disable it before .ajaxSubmit disabling works but ajax submitting stops to work 0_o.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(function(){
      $(".load")
           .ajaxStart(function () {
              $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
          })
         .ajaxComplete(function(){
            $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
         });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myForm = $('YOUR_FORM').find('input'); // finding `input`s should like this

$('#save_form').ajaxSubmit({
  beforeSubmit: function() {
    $(myForm).prop('disabled', true);
    ...
  },
  success: function() {
    $(myForm).prop('disabled', false);
    .....
  },
  error: function() {
    ....
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I do think that disabling the form before submitting will stop the form submittion, but you can disable the input elementes in the form, this should give you the function you want.
eg. add a class like frmdis to every input in your form or to any other input element on the page.

```
$('#save').live('click', function () {

        $('.frmdis').prop('disabled', true);
        alert('before submit');

        $('#save_form').ajaxSubmit({
            success:function (data, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                $('.frmdis').prop('disabled', false);
                alert('success');
                $form.find('.error').remove();
                if (data['result'] == 'success') {
                    $('#success').show("slow");
                }
                else if (data['result'] == 'error') {
                    $('#error').show("fast");
                    //calling procedure to show errors
                }
                $('#load').hide("fast");
            },
```

.
.
.